# How to define a given quotient space $\Bbb{R} ^2$/{$0$}?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, quotient-spaces

I am required to describe the following quotient space: $\Bbb{R} ^2/ \{0\}$.

Now, as far as I understand, a quotient space is a collection  of sets such as $\{v_1 + U , v_2+U , \dots ,v_n + U\}$ where in this case every $v_i \in \Bbb{R}^2$ and $U$ is {$0$}.

So if I take $v_i$ as some vector $(a , b)$ and try finding out $v_1$ + {$0$}, I will have to evaluate
$(a , b)$ + $0$ which makes no sense.

Can I say that the quotient space given is not possible?

Comment: I assume the question means$$\mathbb{R}/\{\mathbf{0}\}=\mathbb{R}/\{(0,0)\}$$

Comment: @PeterForeman That's the thing. In the question its only {$0$} given and that got me confused. I am new to this topic and did not want to take assumptions

Comment: Well as you say it doesn't make any sense with $0\in\mathbb{R}$ because $\{0\}\not\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Your $\textbf{0}=(0,0)$. So $(a,b)+\{(0,0)\}=\{(a,b)\}$.

Comment: Yes, that is wrong. $\{0\}$ can not be a subset of $\Bbb{R}^2$. So actually $\textbf{0}$ means the additive identity $(0,0)$ of $\Bbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 0):

The quotient space $\mathbb{R}^2/\{ \mathbf{0} \}$ is well defined (where $\mathbf{0}= (0, 0) \in \mathbb{R}^2$).
$$ \mathbb{R}^2/\{ \mathbf{0} \} := \{ \mathbf{a} + \mathbf{0}~:~ \mathbf{a} \in \mathbb{R}^2 \} $$
Moreover, a simple map will explain everything.

From the First Isomorphism theorem, for a vector space $V/\mathbb{K}$ and a subspace $W$ of $V$, we have the map $\Psi: V \to W$ such that $\Psi \in \mathcal{L}(V, W)$ and
$$ V/\text{ker}(\Psi) \cong \text{im}(\Psi) $$
From there we have that $$\mathbb{R}^2/\{\mathbf{0}\} \cong \mathbb{R}^2  $$